# Flutter pass dynamic snapshot to another page

Tags: flutter, list, navigation, future, snapshot

I have a page where I get snapshot returned as Future<List<RaceModel>>. Then on my widget I use a ListView.builder to display the data, which is ok:

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
    final controller = Get.put(RaceController());
    var currentSliderValue = 20.0.obs;
    get snapshot => controller.getAllUsers(currentSliderValue.value);

...
            FutureBuilder<List<RaceModel>>(
                future: snapshot,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {

-->> this part is fine.
```

Then I added an appBar to its body, which I want to navigate to another page using the same snapshot data:

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  Racesmap(snap: snapshot)),
);
```

Issue 1: when the navigation is triggered, the request of the snapshot is executed every time, which is consuming data from my DB. I just want to pass the same data.

Issue 2: I'm not able to get values of this snapshot elsewhere than the builder widget. For example if I try to print snapshot value on the navigation function, I got 'Instance of ...'

If anyone could help me on this / or give me a hint, it would be appreciated. :-)

I tried to put the snapshot onto final object to use then on my navigation function without success.
I tries many things.. but I'm not getting everything right from all of this. I'm new on flutter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to fetch data once and then use this fetched data across different pages without making network requests again. One approach you can utilize here is using a state management solution like **GetX**. Since you are already using **Get.put()** method, you are somewhat familiar with **GetX**.

Here is a way to do it:

1- In your **RaceController**, you can have a variable to store your fetched data.

```
class RaceController extends GetxController {
  var raceList = <RaceModel>[].obs;

  fetchRaces(double value) async {
    raceList.value = await getAllUsers(value);
  }
}
```

2- In your main widget, you can use the **RaceController** to fetch and store data.

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final controller = Get.put(RaceController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.fetchRaces(20.0);
  }

  ...
}
```

3- In your **FutureBuilder**, you can use the raceList directly.

```
Obx(() {
  if (controller.raceList.isNotEmpty) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: controller.raceList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(controller.raceList[index].yourFieldName),
        );
      },
    );
  } else {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
})
```

4- When navigating to another page, you can pass the controller itself or just access it directly in the new page.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Racesmap(controller: controller)),
);
```

In the **Racesmap** widget, you can access the data using **widget.controller.raceList**.

This way, you only fetch the data once, store it in the controller, and can use it across different widgets without re-fetching. Remember to handle the disposing of the controller correctly if you don't want to keep the data for the entire app lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you so much Nabil, you bring me the light ;-)